# Best or simplest way to integrate less in yeoman?

Tags: less, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm experimenting with [yeoman](http://yeoman.io).

I want to integrate [less](http://lesscss.org/) into my yeoman or grunt build. But I haven't found I simple way to do it.

I do have found to [yeoman-less](https://github.com/gbrits/yeoman-less) repository which refers to [grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less). But that plugin is quite hard to plugin if you are new to yeoman and grunt. Isn't there a much easier way to plugin less into my yeoman webapp so the less commands are automatically added to the grunt build file?

Thanks for the tips and tricks!

Comment: Are you using a particular generator you want to integrate Less with? Would be easier to give an example then.

Comment: Currently I'm using "yo webapp", but I there is a better generator, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: I tried the solution below, but couldn't get livereload working properly. However, I found a generator specifically for Bootstrap and Less: https://npmjs.org/package/generator-bootstrap-less

Answer (score 19):

Assuming that you scaffold out a new app using `yo webapp` and answer both questions with `No`, your best choice for integrating LESS is [grunt-recess](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-recess) which you need to install first:

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-recess
```

If you dislike the linting rules, you can [customize them](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-recess#options). Feel free to uninstall `grunt-compass` and remove it from the `package.json`.

You then need to replace the `compass` task in the Gruntfile with this:

```
    recess: {
        options: {
            compile: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                src: '{,*/}*.less',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    }
```

You then need to replace all remaining references to the `compass` task with `recess`, so that the resulting Gruntfile looks like [this one](https://paste.welcloud.de/show/9wZikzH1osEOkzjjuJtH/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When I make these changes, though, I'm unable to get livereload working. Did you have similar issues? (I'm running Yeoman Webapp generator 0.2.3)

Comment: @Benmj Try the latest version, there were some issues with livereloading in the earlier versions.

Comment: I was able to get it working. I think there's a typo in @passy's Gruntfile: there should be `recess:dist` instead of `recess:server` in the watch configuration. Here's my Gruntfile: https://paste.welcloud.de/show/9wZikzH1osEOkzjjuJtH/

Comment: Thank you, @DreamSonic. I updated the answer to link to your Gruntfile.

Comment: I have added the recess tasks to my grunt file, but when i run grunt server, i get the following error: No "recess" targets found. This is my grunt file: https://gist.github.com/cremersstijn/7cc6eadb482b6e24c8ea

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I keep finding it. So, here is an up-to-date answer:

Use the "LessApp" generator for Yeoman, found here:
https://github.com/robinpokorny/generator-lessapp

Answer (score 0):

If you get the following error **Expected `recess` to have an identation at 9 instead at 10.**

Please add `recces`  to your *grunt.registerTask*, I've placed mine after the `autoprefixer`

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'recess',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: The error you mention looks like a jshint/jslint error. Order of the task shouldn't matter.